# android/iphone click to call in html

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am creating one HTML mobile website for android & ios device.
I know click to call for both.

ANDROID

```
<a href="tel:2125551212">2125551212</a>
```

iOs

```
<a href="callto:2821229627-7877">Live Support</a>
```

Now, my problem is i have one webpage with click to call link and want that link work for both android / ios

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use `tel:` it will work on iOS, android, blackbarry OS, windows and many more. Using this scheme will work on almost all mobile browsers on.

Comment: Works on Android too, just as you said;)

Comment: what my problem , i have single web page it will open in android and iOs mobile so i want something which works for both device

Comment: Yah! its working in both :) ! Now i have one more question in my mind it will also work for BB, Windows etc.. mobile?

Comment: It's part of the standard uri (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme), so it should work on most of the browsers. There's no warranty, though, as it's up to browser developer to implement proper behaviour.

Comment: This does trigger click to call on Chrome + Windows 7, but a very scary looking message comes up when it is clicked. Be careful if you wish to breed visitor confidence.

Answer (score 1):

You have to recognize the client. Since different phones have different user agents, you can do something like this with JavaScript:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1) {
    txt = "<a href="tel:2125551212">2125551212</a>";
} else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) {
    txt = "<a href="callto:2821229627-7877">Live Support</a>";
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you like it, but the second one is much simpler. You really can use `tel:` for both phones.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me as well.

```
<a href="tel:2125551212">212-555-1212</a>
```

The problem with this is it will break add-ons and extensions that people may use on desktop browsers.

The plain phone number will call on click for Android OS.

```
<p>212-555-1212</p>
```

You can also [track this call with AdWords](http://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722054). I am working on getting it to work with Google Analytics.

Comment: This doesn't address the original poster's question. He is asking how he can get both platforms to make a call with a single link.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to MoyShe's post and not to steal her code (complements) I would add a conditional default for Desktop browsers and other as well using a default **else** statement.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1) {
txt = "<a href="tel:2125551212">2125551212</a>";
} else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) {
txt = "<a href="callto:2821229627-7877">Live Support</a>";
}
<!--what about other devices OS-->
else {
txt = "<span><strong>Phone -</strong> 282-122-9627 ext.7877</span>";
}
```

That way desktop browsers users could also see a phone number as it would display a phone number by default if the device is not of the two handheld device queried.

I am not versed in android, blackberry, IOs, windows, etc...but I would also like to ask or point out my comment section.

```
<!--what about other devices OS-->
```

*(For Newbs- the above line of **commented** code can be removed when pasting in the web page).*

What about blackberry and all the other device OS's? Are they Android or IOs driven OS's? If not, additional code to specifically identify those devices would also need to be created and included in the (else if's) statements.

If I am correct in my unknown question, a **Switch/Case statement** might be cleaner and a better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

as on 
[Msaccess Help Australia](http://www.msaccess.com.au)  www.msaccess.com.au
You only want ordinary text showing on a PC browsers
so put this line in your page

`<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>`

and save the below in a file called javascript.js

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf      ("mobile");

if (isAndroid)
{document.write('<a class="mobilesOnly" href="tel:++61476132591"> Click here to call tel:++61476132591</a>');}
else
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) 
{document.write('<a class="mobilesOnly" href="tel:++61476132591"> Click here to call now:  tel:++61476132591</a>');}
else 
{document.write('Call ++61476132591') ;}
```

don't forget to change the number :)